# Swipe up/down on Surface Pro 4 Windows 10 doesn't work

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, touchpad, device-manager, microsoft-surface-pro

I have Surface Pro 4 connected with a type cover.
Most of the swipe gestures like 3 fingers swipe down, 4 fingers swipe left/right to switch between apps are working flawlessly.

For some reasons, the 2 fingers swipe up/down the page, doesn't work. 
I've tried in Chrome, or even emails, or Word, doesn't work.

I've tried update my Windows 10, and update all my HID keyboards driver. Reboot my PC a bunch of time, it still doesn't work.

Is there anything I should try or look into ?

How would one go about and debug this further ?

Answer (score 0):

I had to reset my Windows machine, and now, it works again.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Your answer could benefit from [more detail](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer). Please edit it to explain *why* your solution addresses the OPs question.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  Can you clarify what you mean by "reset"?

Comment: Sorry guys, I will update the post with screenshots and more details.